# Adding values to server start arguments oracle weblogic

Tags: oracle, weblogic, soa, weblogic12c, weblogic11g

Oracle has suggested to add few parameters to server start arguments which we are adding at Managed server -> configuration -> server start -> Arguments.

Now i need to make this changes in more than 100 domains with 4 managed servers each. I would like to know is there a way to add this in backend at server level so that i shall automate it with scripts. already there are few values under this, i am just appending the below values. can someone throw some light here ? 
below are the values i am trying to add.

```
-Doracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=600000 -Dweblogic.Chunksize=65535 -Dweblogic.jndi.responseReadTimeout=120000 -Dweblogic.jndi.connectTimeout=120000 -Dweblogic.UseEnhancedIncrementAdvisor=false
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this seems like a question which you ought to ask on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/). It's not really about programming so much as server admin.

Comment: all the configuration is on config.xml in each domain, said that you may create a script to modify each config.xml (be careful though)

Comment: These parameters can be set in start scripts or in the remote start config of each server in the domain configuration if you are using the node manager. You first need to check the method which is used to start your servers in every domains.

Comment: @devwebcl i have identified a way to add it to the config.xml. but can i directly update it to config.xml ?

Comment: @Emmanuel Collin , we are using node manager to start the services.

Comment: ok, and how does the node manager starts servers ? Using start scripts ?

Comment: yes, they can be updated directly in the config,xml, then restart servers and new parameters should take changes.

Comment: The best way to do this is through the file setUserOverridesLate.sh as is described by Oracle here https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/12.2.1.3/wcedg/customizing-server-parameters-setuseroverrideslate-script.html#GUID-E74380A4-BDB0-4933-8884-8183D210F0F0

Answer (score 2):

The correct mode is to use **WLST**.

**WLST** is the tool offered by Weblogic to script Domain configurations.
In this way, you could save the configurations on an svc and you can automate this operation.

To add a start parameter to servers or to a cluster you have to write a .py file with the instructions and then launch it with the wlst console.

File example:

```
# JVM PARAMETER MANAGED SERVER
server_jvm_parameters = [{
    "cluster_name": "CLUSTER_NAME",
    "arguments": " -Doracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout=600000 -Dweblogic.Chunksize=65535 -Dweblogic.jndi.responseReadTimeout=120000 -Dweblogic.jndi.connectTimeout=120000 -Dweblogic.UseEnhancedIncrementAdvisor=false"                                                  
  }

def config_jvm_start_parameters(server_jvm_parameters):
  print "config_start_parameters " + str(server_jvm_parameters)
  for current in server_jvm_parameters:
    cluster_name = current['cluster_name']
    arguments = current['arguments']
    managed_servers = current.get('servers', None)

    print 'init configuration start parameters ' + cluster_name

    cluster_bean_path = getPath('com.bea:Name=' + cluster_name + ',Type=Cluster');
    cluster = getMBean('/'+cluster_bean_path); 
    servers = cluster.getServers();  
    for server in servers:
      server_name = server.getName()  
      cmo=cd('/Servers/'+server_name+'/ServerStart/'+server_name)
      argsSetted = False

      if (managed_servers is not None):
        for managed_server in managed_servers:
          managed_server_name = managed_server['managed_name']
          managed_server_arg = managed_server['arguments']
          if (managed_server_name == server_name):
            argsSetted = True
            cmo.setArguments(arguments +  ' ' + managed_server_arg)

      if (not argsSetted):
        cmo.setArguments(arguments)


connect(user, password, host)
edit()
startEdit()
config_jvm_start_parameters(server_jvm_parameters)
save()
activate()
```

And then run the command:

```
$ORACLE_MIDDLEWARE_HOME/oracle_common/common/bin/wlst.sh file.py
```